# Regex to match all parameters in application packets

Tags: regex

I have a list of parameters in many packets that I need to catch them all using regex.
Each parameter will start with `=` and will close with `&`
Example: `addonName=CatchMe1&`
All the parameters are variables and I cant know what they will contain (String, Integer etc.)

Thank You.

```
POST /stringos.txt?addonName=CatchMe1&application=CatchMe2&platform=CatchMe3&platformVersion=CatchMe4&lastVersion=CatchMe5&downloadCount=CatchMe6 HTTP/1.1
Host: Host.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: close

addonName=CatchMe1&application=CatchMe2&platform=CatchMe3&platformVersion=CatchMe4&lastVersion=CatchMe5&downloadCount=CatchMe6
```

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because you don't tell us anything you have tried so far. Also, you should use the code formatting feature. Anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally better to use an URL parser to get those parameters, but if you really want to use RegEx, you could try `(?<==)[^&]+`

See this working example: https://regex101.com/r/bzlYZ2/2

**Explanation:**
`(?<==)[^&?]+` ⇒ the full RegEx
`(?<==)` ⇒ a look-behind (non-capturing), that matches a `=`
`[^&?]+` ⇒ any character that is **not** `&` or `?` (one or more)

This pattern matches the values of your parameters. If you need the keys *and* the values, you could use [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html): `([^&?]+)=([^&]+)` so you have the **key** in group 1 (`$1`) and the **value** in group 2 (`$2`).

Answer (score 0):

For now I managed to use this regex for my problem.

```
.*?=(.*?)&.*?=(.*?)&.*?=(.*?)&.*?=(.*?)&.*?=(.*?)&.*?=(.*?) HTTP/1.1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just be warned that this is a very expensive way of doing it. Also, it's not exactly elegant nor dynamic: What if you have one more/less parameter? You'll have to change your RegEx every time.